# Find / Replace functionality that allows for boundary replacements instead of expressions

Tags: regex, text, language-agnostic, replace

Apologies in advance for the confusing title.  My issue is as follows, I have the following text in about 600 files:

```
$_REQUEST['FOO']
```

I would like to replace it with the following:

```
$this->input->post('FOO')
```

To clarify, I am matching against the following:

```
$_REQUEST any number of A-Za-z\d followed by a ]
```

and replacing it with:

```
$this->input->post( the alphanumeric word from above followed by a )
```

Or in general:

```
Anchor token  TEXT TO KEEP  end anchor token
```

This differs from standard find/replace as I want to retain text inside of two word boundaries.

Is this functionality present in any text editors (Eclipse,np++,etc).  Or am I going to need to write some type of program to parse these 600 files to make the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/\$__REQUEST\[(.*?)]/$this->input->post(\1)/
```

The `.*?` will match everything from `[` to the *first* `]` rather than the last although it's unlikely that it will matter in this case.

By the way the PHP superglobal is `$_REQUEST` rather than `$__REQUEST`

Comment: I fat fingered, will change in the original question.  So that line above will do the replacement as desired?

Comment: It is probably better to use `[^\]]++` rather than `.*?`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I disagree. For one thing, your method would capture the apostrophe. Second, the non-greediness should make it work just fine, as long as the brackets are balanced, which I imagine they are.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I think so, just change `$__REQUEST` to `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @acheong87 Methinks `(.*?)` will capture both apostrophes too, but they are needed in the replacement anyway. A possessive quantifier is significantly faster for non-matching text and as I image whole PHP files are being parsed that is something that needs to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Ah, you're right, actually. Sorry about that. For some reason I didn't think he want the apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Notepad++ using regular expressions. Replace

```
\$_REQUEST\['([^']*)'\]
```

with

```
$this->input->post('$1')
```

If you ever have double-quotes too, you can do use a more complex expression to handle both cases, though I'm not sure Notepad++ supports backreferences; replace

```
\$_REQUEST\[(['"])(.*?)\1\]
```

with

```
$this->input->post($1$2$1)
```

Note that I've reverted to using @ExplosionPills' suggested `(.*?)` here—it may be better, actually.

Comment: Doesn't the first expression need a quantifier on the `[^']` pattern?

Comment: fails.  output becomes:  $this->input->post'foo'  it doesnt havce ('foo')  [missing the parens]

Comment: i got it, you want to have a `\\`` trailing both of the `(` and `)`

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Hm. Typically in regular expressions, you shouldn't have to escape parentheses in the replacing expression. It may be a quirk of Notepad++.

Comment: ah yes, i could see that as that was my test environment :) .  If you edit I can give points back.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Ah, I see. Up to you. ExplosionPills had the better answer.